Thermal stability of materials by first principles
I'm doing a DFT study of monolayers using Quantum espresso. I want to check the thermal stability of layers. It is quoted sometimes in experimental papers that integrity of layer is maintained at 0K-800k, means layer has thermal stability. How to check that using first principles?
I have vague idea that Molecular Dynamics can do this. But I'm not sure about the steps or how to properly implement it.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Much more info needed ;). Monolayer - you mean something free-standing like grapheme in vacuum, or something at an interface like oil on water? Stability - what do you expect to happen at high temperatures: evaporation, sublimation, pyrolysis, or combustion?  You can probably figure out an approximate enthalpy and entropy for pyrolysis with DFT, if you know the main products. Molecular dynamics could give you a melting point but not super accurately. It really depends ;)
